# access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP] in hyperledger fabric with kubenetes?

Tags: kubernetes, blockchain, rancher

I have created a fabric network with kubenetes. All my peers are up and running.

When go to cli shell and execute below command

```
peer channel list
```

I get error as

```
  access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

On peer logs i get below error

```
channel []: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I thought its a certificates issue. So i tested same certificates with docker. but it seems that on docker its working. so let me know what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` 
 was missing in your peer's environment variables.
Please set `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=<msp-dir-of-peer>`